# Android Low fps after Unity 5.3 update

Tags: android, performance, unity-game-engine

I asked this question on Unity Answers but I didn't get any answer.

I've been searching about this problem but I couldn't find anything. Before updating unity to 5.3 the game was running grate but now I have a very low fps >20 and am running it on Samsung Galaxy s6 edge plus so I don't think my phone is poor preforming especially because before updating it was running smooth  here is a screen shot from the profiler if it can help 
[image]

Notice how rendering is insane though I don't have many object it scene the game is just hitting a duck moving from left to right with a hammer (in 3D) I'm also using Legacy shadier because I read that its less expensive than stranded shadier  I also have V Sync on and I noticed an improvement turning it on before turning it on fps was as low as 11. And let me add that on editor it works perfectly at steady 60 fps.

Comment: Which version number did you upgrade from?

Comment: There has been many reports on FPS drop after upgrading, even on empty projects. Basic solution is to downgrade to 5.2 and wait for a few patches.

Comment: Apparently changing it so that only OpenGL ES2 is enabled has fixed the FPS bug on Android for others.

Comment: I upgraded from 5.2.3

Comment: So,I'll try downgrading to 5.2.3 hope every thing goes OK.

Comment: OK, So as expected every thing worked grate after downgrading back to Unity 5.2.3 now I have 59-62 fps which is great I hope Unity will fix issues on 5.3